# Can you set the anchorPoint of the root layer on an NSView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, quartz-graphics

Is it possible to modify the `anchorPoint` property on the root `CALayer` of a layer-backed `NSView`?

I have a view called `myView` and it seems every time I set the `anchorPoint`, it gets overridden in the next run loop. I am doing this:

```
NSView *myView = [[myView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];

//set the root layer
myView.layer = [CALayer layer];
myView.wantsLayer = YES;

//gets overridden on the next run loop
myView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

> On 10.8, AppKit will control the following properties on a CALayer
>   (both when "layer-hosted" or "layer-backed"): geometryFlipped, bounds,
>   frame (implied), position, anchorPoint, transform, shadow*, hidden,
>   filters, and compositingFilter. … Use the appropriate NSView cover
>   methods to change these properties.

Basically it will set the anchor to [0,0] from [0.5,0.5], to account for this i uses something like :

```
+(void) accountForLowerLeftAnchor:(CALayer*)layer
{
    CGRect frame = layer.frame;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame));
    layer.position = center;
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
}
```