# Changed Anchor Point of CALayer in Layer-backed NSView

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I am trying to have a zoom animation run on a layer-backed NSView by animating the transform of the backing layer. The issue I am having with this, is that the animation zooms into the bottom left corner instead of the center of the view. I figured out that this is because NSView sets its backing layer's anchor point to (0, 0), even after I change it to some other value. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814212/can-you-set-the-anchorpoint-of-the-root-layer-on-an-nsview) talks about a similar issue.

I know that to get around this, I could make the view a layer-hosting view. However, I would like to use auto layout, which is why that is not really an option.

Does anyone know another way to get around this behavior and keep the anchor point of the view's backing layer at (0.5, 0.5)? The excerpt from apple's documentation in the post I linked above talks about NSView cover methods. What could such cover method be for the anchor point?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to override the backing layer and pass an anchor point of choice (to be able to zoom from top left, for instance). Here's what I use:

```swift
extension CGPoint {
  static let topLeftAnchor: Self = .init(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
  static let bottomLeftAnchor: Self = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
  static let topRightAnchor: Self = .init(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
  static let bottomRightAnchor: Self = .init(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
  static let centerAnchor: Self = .init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
}

class AnchoredLayer: CALayer {
  public var customAnchorPoint = CGPoint.topLeftAnchor
  
  override var anchorPoint: CGPoint {
    get { customAnchorPoint }
    set { super.anchorPoint = customAnchorPoint }
  }
}

class AnchoredView: NSView {
  required convenience init(anchoredTo point: CGPoint) {
    self.init(frame: .zero)
    self.wantsLayer = true
    self.anchorPoint = point
  }
  
  public override func makeBackingLayer() -> CALayer {
    let roundedLayer = AnchoredLayer()
    return roundedLayer
  }
  
  public var anchorPoint: CGPoint {
    get { (layer as! AnchoredLayer).customAnchorPoint }
    set { (layer as! AnchoredLayer).customAnchorPoint = newValue }
  }
}
```

Then use `AnchoredView` as normal:

```swift
    let myView = AnchoredView(anchoredTo: .topLeftAnchor)

    // Create the scale animation
    let transformScaleXyAnimation = CASpringAnimation()
    transformScaleXyAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    transformScaleXyAnimation.keyPath = "transform.scale.xy"
    transformScaleXyAnimation.toValue = 1
    transformScaleXyAnimation.fromValue = 0.8
    transformScaleXyAnimation.stiffness = 300
    transformScaleXyAnimation.damping = 55
    transformScaleXyAnimation.mass = 0.8
    transformScaleXyAnimation.initialVelocity = 4
    transformScaleXyAnimation.duration = transformScaleXyAnimation.settlingDuration

    myView.layer?.add(transformScaleXyAnimation, forKey: "transformScaleXyAnimation")
...
```

Comment: If I want to use it on NSPanel is it possible to change contentView anchorpoint?